# How can I fix this error, building OmniRom?

Tags: android, compilation, building, custom-rom

Currently, I am building OmniRom for the android device beryllium. First, I downloaded the source. Then I cloned the xiaomi vendor from https://github.com/TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_xiaomi. After that I executed the "breakfast" command with beryllium as parameter. When it finished, I just entered "make -j4"

I got this failure message:

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=9
TARGET_PRODUCT=omni_beryllium
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=kryo300
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a75
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.9.0-8-amd64-x86_64-Debian-GNU/Linux-9-(stretch)
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PQ2A.190205.001
OUT_DIR=/home/benjamin/OMNI/out
============================================
ninja: no work to do.
ninja: no work to do.
wildcard(/home/benjamin/OMNI/out/target/product/beryllium/clean_steps.mk) was changed, regenerating...
wildcard(vendor/xiaomi/whyred/Android.mk) was changed, regenerating...
[24/971] including development/build/Android.mk ...
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: android_stubs_current 
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: metalava_android_stubs_current metalava_android_stubs_current
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: android_system_stubs_current 
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: android_test_stubs_current 
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: metalava_android_system_stubs_current metalava_android_system_stubs_current
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: metalava_android_test_stubs_current metalava_android_test_stubs_current
[539/971] including system/sepolicy/Android.mk ...
system/sepolicy/Android.mk:79: warning: BOARD_SEPOLICY_VERS not specified, assuming current platform version
[971/971] including vendor/xiaomi/tissot/Android.mk ...
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/benjamin/OMNI/out/target/product/beryllium/root/res/images/charger/battery_fail.png'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/benjamin/OMNI/out/target/product/beryllium/root/res/images/charger/battery_fail.png'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/benjamin/OMNI/out/target/product/beryllium/root/res/images/charger/battery_scale.png'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/benjamin/OMNI/out/target/product/beryllium/root/res/images/charger/battery_scale.png'
build/make/core/Makefile:28: warning: overriding commands for target `/home/benjamin/OMNI/out/target/product/beryllium/system/etc/mkshrc'
build/make/core/base_rules.mk:412: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/home/benjamin/OMNI/out/target/product/beryllium/system/etc/mkshrc'
ninja: error: '/home/benjamin/OMNI/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/WfdCommon_intermediates/classes.jar', needed by '/home/benjamin/OMNI/out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/boot-jars-package-check_intermediates/stamp', missing and no known rule to make it
14:54:42 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (02:22 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Can somebody help me, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Wfd common jars in your tree most probably. Try picking this [commit](https://github.com/omnirom/android_device_xiaomi_whyred/commit/e0a1148b55c1e62a6b11c2f1471cf4806df79017) and add relevant Wfd common libs to see whether it works or not